# Pytorch 2D CNN with unlabeled training data from set of 2d numpy arrays: potential problem with batch size or shapes

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I have created a custom dataset to load 2d numpy array data to autoencode with a CNN. I believe the structure of the dataset and resulting batches/tensor shapes are correct. I also checked the shapes through the network down to the linear layer, and it seems correct, but somehow the batch size is always being passed through.

Here is a portion of the code:

```
class UnlabeledTensorDataset(TensorDataset):
    def __init__(self, ):
        X = np.load('dU_X.npy')
        X = X/np.max(X)
        self.samples = X
        self.transform = transforms.Grayscale(1)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        im = self.samples[index]
        im = Image.fromarray(im)
        im = self.transform(im)
        return im

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.samples)
```

```
train_dataset = UnlabeledTensorDataset()
test_dataset  = UnlabeledTensorDataset()

train_transform = transforms.Compose([
transforms.ToTensor(),
])

test_transform = transforms.Compose([
transforms.ToTensor(),
])

train_dataset.transform = train_transform
test_dataset.transform = test_transform

m=len(train_dataset)

train_data, val_data = random_split(train_dataset, [int(m-m*0.2), int(m*0.2)])
batch_size=256

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size)
valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_data, batch_size=batch_size)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)


class Encoder(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, encoded_space_dim,fc2_input_dim):
        super().__init__()
        
        ### Convolutional section
        self.encoder_cnn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 8, 3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(8, 16, 3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 2, 2, stride=2, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(True)
        )
        
        ### Flatten layer
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten(start_dim=1)
                                  
        ### Linear section
        self.encoder_lin = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(3 * 3 * 32, 128),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(128, encoded_space_dim)
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder_cnn(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.encoder_lin(x)
        return x
    
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, encoded_space_dim,fc2_input_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.decoder_lin = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(encoded_space_dim, 128),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(128, 3 * 3 * 32),
            nn.ReLU(True)
        )

        self.unflatten = nn.Unflatten(dim=1, 
        unflattened_size=(32, 3, 3))

        self.decoder_conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, 3, 
            stride=2, output_padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 8, 3, stride=2, 
            padding=1, output_padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(8),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(8, 1, 3, stride=2, 
            padding=1, output_padding=1)
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.decoder_lin(x)
        x = self.unflatten(x)
        x = self.decoder_conv(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x
    
### Define the loss function
loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()

### Define an optimizer (both for the encoder and the decoder!)
lr= 0.001

### Set the random seed for reproducible results
torch.manual_seed(0)

### Initialize the two networks
d = 4

#model = Autoencoder(encoded_space_dim=encoded_space_dim)
encoder = Encoder(encoded_space_dim=d,fc2_input_dim=128)
decoder = Decoder(encoded_space_dim=d,fc2_input_dim=128)
params_to_optimize = [
    {'params': encoder.parameters()},
    {'params': decoder.parameters()}
]

optim = torch.optim.Adam(params_to_optimize, lr=lr, weight_decay=1e-05)

# Check if the GPU is available
device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
print(f'Selected device: {device}')

# Move both the encoder and the decoder to the selected device
encoder.to(device)
decoder.to(device)

### Training function
def train_epoch(encoder, decoder, device, dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer):
    # Set train mode for both the encoder and the decoder
    encoder.train()
    decoder.train()
    train_loss = []
    
    for image in dataloader:
        
        # Move tensor to the proper device
        image = image.to(device)
        # Encode data
        encoded_data = encoder(image)
        # Decode data
        decoded_data = decoder(encoded_data)
        # Evaluate loss
        loss = loss_fn(decoded_data, image)
        # Backward pass
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        # Print batch loss
        print('\t partial train loss (single batch): %f' % (loss.data))
        train_loss.append(loss.detach().cpu().numpy())

    return np.mean(train_loss)`
```

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py:114 in forward
return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (256x128 and 288x128)

Here it seems that my batch size of 256 is being carried through. No matter what the batch size the error is batch_sizex128. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You create the following encoder:

```py
        self.encoder_lin = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(3 * 3 * 32, 128),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Linear(128, encoded_space_dim)
        )
```

The first linear layer expects input of shape `(bs, 288)` (288 = 3 * 3 * 32).

the output of your `encoder_cnn` appears to be of size `(bs, 128)`.

You are sending a tensor of size `(bs, 128)` to a model that expects size `(bs, 288)`, causing the error.